# How to prevent EVURLCache to cache a request with Cache-Control header?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, cache-control

I'm using EVURLCache and the POST request response is cached even if cache-control and Pragma headers are defined :

```
Headers: [
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, x-auth-token
  Content-Type : application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Access-Control-Max-Age : 3600
  Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Server : nginx/1.9.15
  Connection : keep-alive
  Transfer-Encoding : Identity
  X-XSS-Protection : 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff
  Expires : 0
  X-Application-Context : application:dev,docker:8080
  Pragma : no-cache
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
  Date : Thu, 18 Aug 2016 13:57:15 GMT
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
]
```

**How to force EVURLCache not to cache such a request ?**

I'm initializing cache in my app delegate using the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // configuring cache
    EVURLCache.LOGGING = true // We want to see all caching actions
    EVURLCache.activate()

    return true
}
```

Note that I know filters but I wonder if we can just tell it to follow the response header suggested cache behavior

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Updated with AppDelegate code

Comment: Had the exact same issue, opened an issue with the creator of EVURLCache
https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache/issues

Comment: Thanks @SoundShock for reporting the issue and pointing me to this question. It's only one method (storeCachedResponse) where logic for this has to be added. I will have a look at it now.

Answer (score 2):

I have created an update (not yet pushed to GitHub) and would like to have your input. The code for the fix for this is:

```
    var shouldSkipCache: String? = nil

    // check if caching is allowed according to the request
    if request.cachePolicy == NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData {
        shouldSkipCache = "request cache policy"
    }

    // check if caching is allowed according to the response Cache-Control or Pragma header
    if let httpResponse = cachedResponse.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        if let cacheControl = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Cache-Control"] as? String {
            if cacheControl.lowercaseString.containsString("no-cache")  || cacheControl.lowercaseString.containsString("no-store") {
                shouldSkipCache = "response cache control"
            }
        }

        if let cacheControl = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Pragma"] as? String {
            if cacheControl.lowercaseString.containsString("no-cache") {
                shouldSkipCache = "response pragma"
            }
        }
    }

    if shouldSkipCache != nil {
        // If the file is in the PreCache folder, then we do want to save a copy in case we are without internet connection
        let storagePath = EVURLCache.storagePathForRequest(request, rootPath: EVURLCache._preCacheDirectory) ?? ""
        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(storagePath) {
            EVURLCache.debugLog("CACHE not storing file, it's not allowed by the \(shouldSkipCache) : \(request.URL)")
            return
        }
        EVURLCache.debugLog("CACHE file in PreCache folder, overriding \(shouldSkipCache) : \(request.URL)")
    }
```

In short this means that:

- If the request was created while indicating that cached data should beignored then the response will not be written to the cache
- If the response has a Cache-Control header that contains no-cache or no-store then the response will not be written to the cache
- If the response has a Pragma header that contains no-cache then the response will not be written to the cache
- All above will be ignored if the file is already in the cache. (then at least it should be updated)

Comment: I'll, check it asap. I think it's a good start but probably more work to be fully compliant with the http cache headers spec should be done, especially about cache TTL that is not checked here.

Comment: The TTL is already checked in the cachedResponseForRequest method. See the cacheItemExpired function.

Comment: Nice, i just had a very quick look at it, sorry.

Comment: I just pushed the modification to GitHub and Cocoapods as version 2.10.0